# SQL Server CE - Not letting me add a Varbinary column of max length

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I've been struggling in vain to add a `VARBINARY` column of `MAX` length to my table.

I'm trying with this:

```
ALTER TABLE Databases ADD dbFile VARBINARY(MAX)
```

and it's returning:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 44,Token in error = MAX ]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the syntax there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this TechNet page (Data Types Supported in SQL Server CE)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275635%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), SQL Server CE supports `varbinary` only up to 8000 bytes long.

If you need a larger column, you have to use `image` instead.

Comment: this is what the recent sql server docs tells you about it: "The ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead."

Comment: @JoséAlvarez: yes - this applies to the **full** SQL Server editions - but ***NOT*** to SQL Server **Compact Edition** (CE) - which is out of support itself, btw, by now.....